# JBPMJunitbaseTestCase for call activity

Tags: jbpm

I need to write unit test case for JBPM process and mock the call activity through Junit. Plus, I don't want the sub process to be called, rather mock it and return the mock response.


**Eg. Main process has following tasks**

              Script Task

              User Task

              Call Activity - This calls the sub process

        **Sub Process has following tasks**

           User task

           Service Task to call rest service

           Then return the service response back to the caller

We are writing the the Junit test cases by extending the **JBPMJunitbaseTestCase** provided by **jbpm-test**.

 As per this, when the main process is initiated by the JUnit test case, 
  Script task is getting completed, 
  Using Task service we are able to complete the user task as well within the test case. 
  Call activity, by default the process initiates the instance for the sub process and starts executing tasks inside it.

But I don't want the Call Activity to initiate the sub process instance rather I  want to mock it, so that I can run the unit test case for the main process independent of the sub process.
 Please let me know what are the options available.